# how to update a string which is copied into array

Tags: python, csv

Currently, am converting CSV to an array using python. At first, am copying all the headers from CSV to the array. While copying from CSV I need to amend additional characters to the column name.

**eg:** from CSV, I use append function to write it into the array.

```
finarr.append([cmerow[headarr.index('Action')],cmerow[headarr.index('Reject Reason')]
```

**requirement :** while writing into array, one of the column's name need to be modified as shown below :

```
([cmerow[headarr.index('Action/hero')],cmerow[headarr.index('Reject Reason')]
```

**csv :** Action  | Reject reason

**array :** Action/hero | Reject reason  - (o/p Expectation).

Comment: I'm obviously missing something, can you not use conditional logic to populate a variable and then use that to set the column name rather than hard coding it?

Answer (score 0):

How about you try using pandas. It will take care of header and data, no need to import them individually. Referencing the columns is pretty easy too. Here is how you can make use of it.

```
import pandas as pd

# Import the data.csv data: data
cars = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
#rename your column headers like this
cars.columns=['country_cd','cars_per_cap','country','drives_direction']
print(cars)
print(cars["country_cd"],cars["drives_direction"])
```

Let me know if it works for you.